# How to make this layout?

Tags: css, layout

### The layout

[image]

I really dont have any idea of where to begin to make this with DIVs or with tables specially with the fact that i need a top-backgroud and a botton-background. Please i need orientation with this, if you can make the css with the names i put on the image i will understand the code whitout any explanations. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have look if this is](http://tallymobile.com/test2.html) what you were after (TESTED ON SAFARI 5.0)
If yes code is as given below

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    * {margin:0px;padding:0px;border:0px;}

    body{background:#e8a7aa;}

    #bg-top{height:200px;width:100%;background:#008a2b;display:block;float:left;}

    #container{float:left;width:900px;z-index:100;margin-left:150px;margin-top:-700px;}

    #header{background:#3d2627;height:180px;}

    #content{background:#94101e;height:340px;}

    #footer{background:#3d2627;height:180px;}

    #bg-bottom{height:200px;width:100%;background:#008a2b;display:block;margin-top:300px;float:left;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg-top"></div>
        <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
        <div id="container">
           <div id="header"></div>
           <div id="content"></div>
           <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
 </head>
```

Will appreciate any other comments as well, cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'm not a CSS expert but I'll see what I can come up with, probably some one else has a better answer. Assuming you want to fill the entire browser window, I'd start out with three divs.

One for left, one for middle, one for right. You can make them float:left and give width in percentages if you want to fill the window. If you want to center this entire thing, give them absolute widths, put them in a parent div and then center the parent with margin auto

After that, you can just fill the three divs with inner divs. Give them the right widths and heights and they will automatically line up underneath eachother. After that, assign backgrounds to the divs using CSS.

Edit: I forgot to say, there is a clear:left or clear:both style that you can use if after the floating divs, you need to go back to "normal" div behavior

Comment: I don’t think his mock-up suggests any need for left and right. I think the areas on the left and right just show what the background is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Is this homework? If so, you’re going to need to learn research skills other than “ask Stack Overflow”.

That said:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background: #dfaaaa;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .TOP-Background {
        background: url(TOP-background.gif) left top repeat-x;
    }

    .BOTTOM-Background {
        background: url(BOTTOM-background.gif) left bottom repeat-x;);
    }

    .HEADER,
    .Content,
    .FOOTER {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .HEADER,
    .FOOTER {
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #3a2727;
    }

    .Content {
        min-height: 801px;
        background-color: #8b1d23;
    }
    </style>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="TOP-Background">
    <div class="BOTTOM-Background">
        <div class="HEADER">
            HEADER: W=900px H=200px
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
            Content: W=900px
        </div>
        <div class="FOOTER">
            FOOTER: W=900px H=200px
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, im using this to understand the think. One last question, how do you get out the space between the divs and the browser?

Comment: @DomingoSL: “im using this to understand the think” — I’ll have to work a bit harder to understand that! “how do you get out the space between the divs and the browser?” Ah yes, `body{margin: 0;}` does that. I’ve edited the answer accordingly.